# UIBarButtonItem Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

Necesitaria poder centrar esta imagen en el medio de mi UIBarButtonItem

Actualmente se ve :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que me gustaria

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo Swift

```
    func setupNavigationBar(showBack:Bool, showMenu:Bool, showFilters: Bool)
    {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        var leftItemTitle = UIBarButtonItem()

        if (showFilters)
        {
            let logoMenu = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logoMenu"))
            logoMenu.sizeToFit()
            logoMenu.frame =  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 130, height: 50)
            leftItemTitle = UIBarButtonItem(customView: logoMenu)
        }
        else
        {
            let titleLabel = UILabel()
            titleLabel.text = self.menuText
            titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
            titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
            titleLabel.sizeToFit()
            leftItemTitle = UIBarButtonItem(customView: titleLabel)
        }

        let sideMenuButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage.init(named: "sideMenu"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(sideMenuPressed))
        sideMenuButtonItem.tintColor = UIColor.white

        let backMenuButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage.init(named: "backButton"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(backPressed))
        backMenuButtonItem.tintColor = UIColor.white

        if(showBack){
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [backMenuButtonItem,leftItemTitle]
        }
        else if(showMenu){
            self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = [sideMenuButtonItem]

//            // AGREGO LOGO DEL MEDIO
//            let titleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:150, height:40))
//            let titleImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "logo"))
//            titleImageView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:titleView.frame.width, height:titleView.frame.height)
//            titleView.addSubview(titleImageView)


            let titleView1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:1150, height:10))
            let titleImageView1 = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "txtnaranja"))
            titleImageView1.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:titleView1.frame.width, height:titleView1.frame.height)
            titleView1.addSubview(titleImageView1)
          self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView1;


//            self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;
        }
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = Utils.Color.COLOR_00356a

        if let hidden = navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden
        {
            if(hidden)
            {
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
            }
            else
            {
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
            }
        }
    }
```

Desde ya Gracias

Comment: hola, donde pones como te gustaria que se viera cual es la imagen que esta centrada? no queda muy claro que es lo que necesitas

Comment: @ErickSilva si erick la primer imagen me gustaria que ocupara todo el ancho de la pantalla pero solo eh podido dejarla de la mitad para adelante

Answer (score 3):

La razón de que aparezca en el medio es porque intentas agregar a la propiedad "self.navigationItem.titleView" entonces las coordenadas comienzan en medio de la pantalla, intenta agregar "titleView1" al navigationBar

```
self.navigationBar.addSubview(titleView1)
```

Comment: En cuanto pueda probarlo vengo a dejarte el feedback

Answer (score -2):

```
self.navigationBar.addSubview(titleView1)navigationBar.add
```

Comment: Creo que boy bien

Comment: Hola, las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad. Deberías editar tu respuesta para añadir una descripción del código que compartes (qué hace, dónde iría, cómo soluciona el problema). Lee [answer] para más información.